# LINQ join multiple tables by same column

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have one table **Texting**, that I need to join with another two tables **Student** and **Staff** to search for information about these 2 tables.

**Student** fields:

1. Id
2. Name
3. ... and a bunch of other fields specific to student

**Staff** fields:

1. Id
2. Name
3. ... and a bunch of other fields specific to staff

**Texting** fields:

1. Id
2. PersonId // contains either student ID or staff ID
3. PersonTypeId // indicates whether PersonId is of type student or staff (student = 1, staff = 2)

Now I need to write a linq query to search the table Texting either by student or staff name but I am stuck on the linq to achieve this.

```
var query = (from t in texting
             join s in studentBo.GetListQuery()
             on t.PersonId equals s.Id
             join st in staffBo.GetListQuery()
             on t.PersonId equals st.Id
             where ...
             select t);
```

This joins the tables together but it doesnt care what the PersonId type is so it's all mixed. How do i specify so that it joins the PersonId correctly according to the right PersonTypeId? It seems like nothing else can be appended on the on clause or where clause to make this happen = (.

Comment: You only select `Texting` items, so you don't need the joins. You can use `from t in texting where studentBo.GetListQuery().Any(...)` etc. I hope that everything is `IQueryable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a `name`, and you want all `Textings` that refer to a `Student` with this name, and all `Textings` that refer to a member of `Staff` with this Name.

My advice would be to concat the Student textings with the Staff textings. You could do that in one big LINQ statements, however this would make it quite difficult to understand. So I'll do it in two steps, then Concat it in one query:

```
const int student = 1;
string name = "William Shakespeare";

var studentTextings = textings.Where(texting => texting.PersonTypeId == student)
    .Join(students.Where(student => student.Name == name),

    texting => texting.PersonId,    // from every Texting take the foreign key
    student => student.Id,          // from every Student take the primary key

    // parameter resultSelector:
    // from every texting with its matching student make one new:
    (texting, studentWithThisTexting) => new
    {
        // Select the Texting properties that you plan to use
        Id = texting.Id,
        ...
    }
```

In words: from all Textings, keep only those Textings that refer to a student, so you know that the foreign key refers to a primary key in the table of Students. From all Students keep only those Students that have the requested name.

Join all remaining Textings and the few remaining Students that have this name on primary and matching foreign key.

Do something similar for members of Staff:

```
const int staff = 2;
var staffTextings = textings.Where(texting => texting.PersonTypeId == staff)
    .Join(staffMembers.Where(staffMember => staffMember.Name == name),

    texting => texting.PersonId,    // from every Texting take the foreign key
    staffMember => staffMember.Id,  // from every Staff member take the primary key

    // parameter resultSelector:
    (texting, staffMembers) => new
    {
        // Select the Texting properties that you plan to use
        Id = texting.Id,
        ...
    }
```

Now all you have to do is Concat these two. Be aware: you can only Concat similar items, so the resultSelector in both Joins should select objects of exactly the same type.

```
var textingsOfPersonsWithThisName = studentTextings.Concat(staffTextings);
```

### There is room for improvement!

If you look closely, you'll see that the textings table will be scanned twice. The reason for this, is because your database is not normalized.

Can it be, that a Texting for a Student will ever become a Texting for a member of Staff? If not, my advice would be to make two tables: StudentTextings and StaffTextings. Apart from that queries will be faster, because you don't have to check `PersonType`, this also has the advantage that if later you decide that a StudentTexting differs from a StaffTexting, you can change the tables without running into problems.

If you really think that sometimes you need to change the type of a texting, and you don't want to do this by creating a new texting, you also should have two tables: one with StudentTextings, and one with StaffTextings, both tables having a one-to-one relations with a Texting.

So Students have one-to-many with StudentTextings, which have one-to-one with Textings. Similar for Staff and StaffTextings.

So Student [4] has 3 StudentTextings with Id [30], [34], [37]. Each of these StudentTextings have a foreign key StudentId with value [4]. Each StudentTexting refers to their own Texting with a foreign key: [30] refers to texting [101], so it has foreign key 101, etc.

Now if texting [101] has to become a texting for Staff [7], you'll have to delete the StudentTexting that refers to [101] and create a new StaffTexting that refers to Staff [7] and Texting [101]

By the way, since the combination [StudentId, TextingId] will be unique, table StudentTextings can use this combination as primary key. Similar for StaffTextings

Answer (score 0):

You will have to merge Student and Staff tables, otherwise all your queries will be too complicated, since you will have to use Union

```
Person

Id
Name
PersonType

Texting

Id
PersonId
```

and query

```
var query = (from t in texting
             join p in person
             on t.PersonId equals p.Id
                  where ...
             select t);
```

PS if you  still want a query with 2 tables instead of one, you will have to  post the real code.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do these as two separate queries, project to a new type and then union the results.  Messy, but here's how.

First get your students:

```
var textingStudents = (
    from s in students
    join t in texting on s.Id equals t.PersonId
    where t.PersonTypeId == 1
    select new { id = s.Id, personTypeId = 1, name = s.Name }).ToList();
```

Now get your staff in almost the exact same way:

```
var textingStaff = (
    from s in staff
    join t in texting on s.Id equals t.PersonId
    where t.PersonTypeId == 2
    select new { id = s.Id, personTypeId = 2, name = s.Name }).ToList();
```

Now you can union the two:

```
var allTextingPeople = textingStudents.Union(textingStaff);
```

If you need additional properties then add then to the anonymous type declared in the `select` statement - remember, the type will need to have the same properties in both the `textingStudents` and `textingStaff` result.  Alternatively, define a class and do a `select new MyUnionClass { ... }` in both queries.

**Edit**
You're going to probably get into a world of hurt with the current approach you've outlined.  If you're using a relational database (i.e. sql server) you almost certainly are not defining constraints such as foreign keys on your `Texting` table meaning you'll end up with ID clashes and will definitely end up with bugs later down the road.  Best approach is probably to have one table to represent `Staff` and `Student` (let's call it `Person` with a column defining the "type" of person - the column itself will be foreign key link to another table with your list of `PersonTypes`

Comment: Better to use `Concat` instead of `Union`. And why not combine them in one query?

Comment: Agreed, Concat would probably be better here.  You cannot do a single query here as the data model in its current form will not support it - the `Texting` table has an `ID` column but that contains the ID of either the `Student` or `Staff` table - it's not truly one-to-one (one-to-(one-OR-one))?

Comment: You are thinking as EF Core developer and from some model perspective. It is normal SQL, why not just generate it?